# How to know in which array the data is located in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

It's me again :P I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad0xsis
            [name] => zad0xsis
            [1] => http://es.gravatar.com/userimage/17503042/86ae3c2e40e7b5cdde3935c57e2da86b.jpg?size=100
            [avatar] => http://es.gravatar.com/userimage/17503042/86ae3c2e40e7b5cdde3935c57e2da86b.jpg?size=100
            [2] => f4a42dce15cebcead096b65191a206eb
            [password] => f4a42dce15cebcead096b65191a206eb
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad0xsis1
            [name] => zad0xsis1
            [1] => http://es.gravatar.com/userimage/17503042/86ae3c2e40e7b5cdde3935c57e2da86b.jpg?size=1100
            [avatar] => http://es.gravatar.com/userimage/17503042/86ae3c2e40e7b5cdde3935c57e2da86b.jpg?size=1100
            [2] => f4a42dce15cebcead096b65191a206eb
            [password] => f4a42dce15cebcead096b65191a206eb
        )

)
```

Now, how could I know if, for example, `[name] => zad0xsis1` is on `array[0]` or `array[1]`?
I thought of having a value (0 for example) and if PHP doesn't find that data there, look in the next by adding 1 to that value, but that could be so slow with a lot of users

Comment: Maybe you can speed up things by using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function findIndexByName ($array, $name) {
  foreach ($array as $index => $entry)
     if ($entry['name'] === $name) return $index;
  return null; // or "false", or "-1", or whatever 
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But I would return `FALSE`, considering this is more typical of what PHP returns when it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Brad: Its (as always) up to you, what you would return, but I would recommend `null`, because by definition `null` means something like "nothing", what (in my opinion) fits here very well.

Comment: Agreed, however [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [next](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) (among other array-based functions) all return `FALSE` when there is no acceptable value to return.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data, you should put it in a database instead of keeping it all in memory. That way, you can easily use a SELECT statement to retrieve the information.

If you must have it in an array like this:

If the data is sorted by the key you're looking for, you can binary-search through the information.

If not, there's nothing much you can do aside from a

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) { 
    if (...) { 
        $found = $key; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be slower than check every element of array if you don't save any other data.
But If for example, users sorted by name you can do it faster

Answer (score 0):

With arrays alone, you can't do any better than just looking at array[0], then array[1], all the way to array[length] to find the name you want. Arrays are a linear data structure.

Believe it or not, even with 10,000 users this is a roughly zero-time operation. Computers are very fast and looking at each element of an array is cheap.

Have you considered keeping the array sorted by name? Use ksort to sort by name (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) and then use a binary search (this is not implemented by default in php, but there's lots of good code available (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php and search for 'binary search') A binary search is much faster than a linear search because it uses the fact that the array is sorted and jumps around rather than checking each one.

Not however that sorting after every single time you add a user is actually pretty expensive compared to just linearly searching the array. Either add users correctly so that the array remains sorted, or just use a linear search as you've described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't youindex array on name if name is going to be unique
e.g
Array
(
    [zad0xsis] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad0xsis
            [name] => zad0xsis
        )

```
[zad0xsis1] => Array
    (
        [0] => zad0xsis1
        [name] => zad0xsis1

    )
```

)

or else create another array which store indexes against name e.g
Array(
[zad0xsis1] => Array(
               [0] => 1 //indexes of main array with name zad0xsis1
               )
)